# Reactions between Ca(OH)2 and CO2, and Sr(OH)2 and CO2

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, aqueous-solution, solutions

So I'm doing an investigation, and it involves using supersaturated solutions of Ca(OH)2 and of Sr(OH)2. I notice that there's always a flaky precipitate formed on top. I need to know about the reactions with carbon dioxide. Is it carbonate that's formed? Or is it hydrogen carbonate? Why?

Comment: In my opinion nothing prevents both carbonates and bicarbonates from forming those flakes on the surface; out of curiosity, why is it so crucial to determine which one is it?

Comment: Although knowing the identity of the precipitate is not really significant to my results in any ways, it's very important that I discuss it since the investigation is for my IB Chemistry Extended Essay. I am required to discuss basically everything going on in the solution in as much detail as possible. I just thought I'd probably be marked down if it I had no idea what's going on in my solutions..

Comment: Interesting, I didn't think of the possibility that it's both. Could be. Thanks!

Comment: it is calcium carbonate that is forming.

Answer (score 1):

Your solid is the respective carbonate. Group II bicarbonates can form aqueous solutions, but [do not form stable solids](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Calcium_bicarbonate), ergo the solid flakes must be carbonate and formed along the lines of:

$$\ce{Ca(OH)2 (aq)+ 2CO2 (aq/g) <=> Ca^2+ + 2(HCO3)- (aq) <=> CaCO3 (s) + CO2 (aq/g)}$$